# How to apply a macro/vba formula to specific cells

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to apply vba formula to designated cells. The vba I am working on would be: If I type something on C2, a date stamp will be automatically put in D2.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Column <> 3 Then Exit Sub
If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
With Target.Offset(0, 1)
.Value = Now
.NumberFormat = "MM/DD/YYYY"
End With
End Sub
```

However, if I typed something on C1, a date stamp will appear as well. How can I limit the range of the vba? For example, I just want the date stamp from D2 to D5.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first answer is right, however here is the full version of it

Paste this in the Project of the table, not as a VBA module

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)


Dim WorkRng As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim xOffsetColumn As Integer


Set WorkRng = Intersect(Application.ActiveSheet.Range("C2:C5"), Target)
xOffsetColumn = 1
If Not WorkRng Is Nothing Then

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    For Each rng In WorkRng
        If Not VBA.IsEmpty(rng.Value) Then
            rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).Value = Now
            rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).NumberFormat = "mm-dd-yyyy"
        Else
            rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).ClearContents
        End If
    Next
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can apply `Intersect` function to check if target falls into the desired range, like this

```
 Dim dr As Range
 Set dr = Range("C2:C5")

 If Not Intersect(target, dr) Is Nothing Then
     ... it is OK, go ahead

 EndIf
```

Comment: Hi, I am really new to VBA... I am not sure where should I add the Intersect function. Would you mind letting me know? Thanks a lot.